# double integral to find volume of torus

Tags: integration

I don't know if I id it write or not. But I am pretty sure It works in case of cylindrical Coordinate. Now I need Cartesian and I got too confused: [image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: If it's not homework, why do you need to integrate using Cartesian coordinates as well? Cylindrical is much easier and more appropriate for this problem.

Comment: It is not a homework, but I am trying to learn. Sometimes in our exams they want us using Cartesian and I am not capable in that part.

Comment: Okay - have a look at the partial answer I've posted below and try to finish the problem. I'll post some additional details once you tell me where you're getting stuck.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Regions of Integration]

We will calculate the volume of a torus by calculating the volume of the torus lying in the first octant ($x$, $y$ and $z$ are all positive) and then multiplying that value by eight.

The integration in the first octant is split into two pieces. We will integrate with respect to $x$ first from zero to $a-b$ taking into account the changing upper and lower limits of integration for $y$, then we integrate from $a-b$ to $a+b$ where only the upper limit of integration for $y$ changes.

I will add the rest of the details once I've seen your attempt to finish the problem.